# How to run VBScript in Windows NT 4?

Tags: vbscript, wsh, nt4

I have a VBScript which I am scheduling to run daily on many Windows servers. In Windows 2000 and 2003, the script worked fine as the two OS have csript.exe. However, in Windows NT 4, it does not seem to have this executable.

Is there an alternative/option to run the VBScript in Windows NT 4?

Answer (score 5):

You need WSH 5.6.  It should be available on Windows Update or you can download it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20060901115837/download.microsoft.com/download/4/c/9/4c9e63f1-617f-4c6d-8faf-c2868f670c1c/Windows9x-Script56-KB917344-x86-enu.exe).  You know NT4 isn't supported any more? `</serverfault>`

Answer (score 3):

According to this MSDN article, WSH 5.6 was available and ran on NT 4.0:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974613.aspx

However, when I go to the Download Center to get Windows Script Host, the 5.6 version only claims to be avaialble for Windows 2000 and Windows XP. There is a newer version, 5.7, but it says it's only supported on XP.

Download Center: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/results.aspx?freetext=windows+script+host&displaylang=en&stype=s_basic

So, perhaps Microsoft removed NT because it has been end-of-lifed? Or perhaps they did a minor update to 5.6 that made it incompatible with NT 4.0.

Comment: There was a separate install for 2000+XP, which still survives because of the lifecycling of 2000.